# Pythonic way to modify list element if condition is met

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have something like this:

```
myListOfLists = [["descrA",True,3],["descrB",True,5],["descrB",True,65],..]
```

For each element in the list i need to set `myListOfLists[element][1]` to False if `myListOfLists[element][2] <= 30`.

`myListOfLists` should become:

```
[["descrA",False,3],["descrB",False,5],["descrB",True,65],..]
```

What is the best approach in python to do that?

Answer (score 6):

There are probably lots of ways to do it, depending on what you mean by "best approach in python". This is one of them:

```
for i in myListOfLists:
    if i[2] <= 30:
        i[1] = False
```

Since "best" could mean: fast, memory efficient, readable etc you can check which method suits your needs.

For example to check speed you can use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#module-timeit) and compare various solutions.

---

What "best" should not mean, is "[unnecessarily complex](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)".

Comment: Sure,thanks,but I'm pretty sure there is a best pythonic way to do that.any ideas?

Comment: @jul What does 'best' mean? Readable, faster, memory efficient?

Comment: I.e. Is it possibile to have it in a single line?

Comment: @jul: Not really. You _could_ do it as a one-liner, using a list comprehension, eg `myListOfLists = [[i,k>30,k] for i,j,k  in myListOfLists]`, but this is less efficient, since it has to rebuild the entire list, rather than just modifying those elements where the Boolean gets changed to `False`.

Comment: @jul: That's a really strange definition of "Pythonic", since Python is the language that (in)famously _requires_ human-readable newlines and indentation.

Comment: @jul It is possible to get it in one line. Is it a good idea? Probably no. Imagine you write 10,000 lines of code. 2 months later if your code is not readable you will waste more time (therefor more money) to fix it.

Comment: @jul: You may like to read this Meta Q&A [Short (complex) “pythonic” code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287624/4014959)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this best pitonic way:

```
[(elem, False, num) if num <= 30 else (elem, cond, num) for (elem, cond, num) in myListOfLists]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(elem, cond and (num > 30), num) for (elem, cond, num) in myListOfLists]
```

improving on the compactness of @Mikhail's answer